# Samsung Glaxy S5 Wifi Not in Range

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have Samsung Glaxy S5 device with some other devices. The Wifi is working every device except in Glaxy S5 device. But when I go to Wifi settings I see 2 connections 1) MyWifi 2) NVRAM Warning: Err = 0x10. When I select MyWifi and put the password. It says 'Authenticating' then it will show 'Not in Range'. Tried everything but nothing is working for me.

Comment: It might help to be a little more detailed on the "everything" part on your question – or we can only suggest to try "something other" ;)

Comment: @Izzy, I mean reboot, disabled MAC filtering, etc

Comment: That's something. Now for the "etc", please :) Honestly: please be as precise as possible, or you'll end up in a loop with people suggesting something, and you saying "I did that already" (and please, [edit] those details into your question: with the comments list getting longer, people will stop reading them). There are many possibilities, e.g. removing the AP and re-adding it in your configuration, doing a complete factory-reset, and more.

Comment: Is it a 5GHz access point? There is a known problem where some phones running recent android builds cannot access 5GHz APs. I have this problem on my Nexus 4.